# (Python) Displaying the power of and the answer

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to display two parts of a problem. As of right now if I can only display the answer. So if I had pow(2,3) it will show 8. However I need to display the 3 as well as the answer. How might I go about displaying these?

Comment: Can you show us your code and what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hopefully I do this right. file = open(input("Enter a file name: "), 'w')

weights = 0

while weights != -999:
    weights = int(input("Enter weight or enter -999 when done: "))
    if weights == -999:
        break
    file.write(str(weights)+'\n')
    print (weights)

pow1 = pow(2,3)

file.write(str(pow1)+'\n')

file.close()

Comment: @Psirebral please edit your question to include your code. Paste it in, select the whole code, and press "Ctrl+K" to format it as a code block

Answer (score 1):

There's too many ways to do it to show everything, so I'll show you how *I'D* do it, and hope that helps.

```
def question(f, *args):
    print("{f}({args}) == {ans}".format(f=f.__name__,
                                        args=', '.join(args),
                                        ans = f(*args)))

>>> question(pow,2,3)
pow(2,3) == 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply print the variable?

```
number = 2
toWhatPower = 3
print(pow(number,toWhatPower)) #displays the 8
print(toWhatPower) #displays the 3
```

in your case it'll be something like

```
file = open(input("Enter a file name: "), 'w') 
weights = 0 
while weights != -999: 
    weights = int(input("Enter weight or enter -999 when done: ")) 
    if weights == -999: 
        break 
file.write(str(weights)+'\n') 
print (weights) 
toWhatPower = 3
pow1 = pow(2,toWhatPower) 
file.write(str(pow1)+'\n')
print(toWhatPower)
file.close()
```

Though since your power does seem to be hardcoded, I don't see why you couldn't just `print(3)` if needed.

Comment: That would work. Though I do have to do multiple numbers. Like 2,3 , 2,4 , and so on. I could just do a variable for each though that'd look a little messy.

Comment: Your code doesn't reflect these multiple numbers? If you update your code, maybe someone could offer a more elegant solution.